# JVM performance PredictedLoadedClassCount and memory used for unique classes loaded

Tags: java, performance, memory

Want to use PredictedLoadedClassCount, but not sure what values to give to it, so that more classes are held in memory. Our program loads a bunch of classes and re-uses them - like I guess any server program, so would like to give Java enough memory so none need be reloaded. not using Spring or other AOP/ proxy things, but are using a bunch of other open source jars.

Goal is to give JVM enough memory so it does not need to load and unload classes which we know are all used throughout execution.

Question is-> has anyone got safe values for this? Can we see what is the current used size of core unique classes loaded so we can increase it?

Comment: “not sure what values to give to it”— then don’t use this option. Why do you think you are smarter than the JVM?

Comment: Saw a video on youtube by a oracle person which said can give a higher value. Unfortunately cannot see that video now as behind a firewall. I do not think 'm smarter than the JVM or its creators but apparently its been optimized for apps that do not use so much memory or classes hence we override the -MX parameter or java runs out of memory. so yes i beleive we can give hints to make it work better in our particular situation

Comment: this might be the URL http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6qx_zvpOyI  not sure have a few saved in an email from when at home. (home net not working so cannot go back and see)

Comment: @Holger Sawa  video on the same http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6qx_zvpOyI where it was suggested